# LIKE in Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nosql

Is using regular expression the (only/best) way to use `LIKE` (as in SQL) functionality in mongoose?

My example:

```js
Thing.find({
  name: new RegExp('^' + req.body.name, "i")
})
.limit(5)
.sort('-rating')
.lean(true)
.exec(
  function (err, things) {
    res.send(things);
  }
);
```

Answer (score 2):

Since it is the only way in MongoDB (except using a [text index](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-text/) which has some constraints), it is the best way.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can only achieve the same behaviour with javascript. Something like below would do the conversion of `LIKE` to `RegExp`.

*(Didn't test, so might not work as it is.)*

```
function createLikeRegex(query) {
  query = query
    .replace(/[.?*+^$[\]\\(){}|-]/g, '\\$&')
    .replace(/(^|[^\\\])%#/g, '\\$&');

  if (! query.startsWith('%')) {
    query = '^' + query;
  }

  if (! query.endsWith('%')) {
    query += '$';
  }

  return new RegExp(query, 'i');
}
```